# Complex numbers with fractions

Tags: python

So I need to hold something like this:

```
complex(fractions.Fraction(1, 3), fractions.Fraction(1, 3))
```

but python is changing fraction to floating point, and since I don't want to use floating point and stay with fractions is there any other implementation of complex numbers that can do what I want? or maybe there is a possibile way to do a small change to current implementation?

Comment: Possible starting point: https://github.com/gladstonedigital/mathvis/blob/master/mathvis/cfractions.py

Comment: you probably can subclass complex and replace the types with fractions

Comment: @Nullman doing that would most likely break all methods defined for `complex` (or, at the very least, implicitly convert the stored values to floats before doing calculations)

Comment: i wast checking this code above before while googling the problem, and it's slightly different, these are fractions that can hold coplex numbers, could you pelase elaborate the subclass part? I am kinda new to python

Comment: oh so it's not possible, ths subclass solution, does numpy or something else have different implementation of complex numbers?

Comment: @apologiessirnoclue "Implementation of complex numbers (a+b*j) where the real and imaginary components are represented as Fraction instances", how is that different from what you'd like to have? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: okay, I think I was wrong it might work, thank you

Answer (score 3):

You could just use `sympy`.

```
from sympy import sympify, I, re, im, expand

z = sympify(1)/3+I/3
```

Notice that I had to use sympify(1) since otherwise 1/3 would evaluate to a float rather than a sympy expression. Now you can do calculations with complex numbers like so

```
re(z) -> 1/3
```

```
im(z) -> 1/3
```

```
z*z= -> (1/3+i/3)**2
```

```
expand(z*z) -> (2*i)/9
```

Comment: I'd say "You SHOULD use Sympy" …

Comment: Or `z = (1 + I) / 3` without `sympify`

Comment: @stef yea that works too but has the disadvantage that it does not explicitly show how to resolve the 1/3 problem in general.